# How to use map to process column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this,

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


   calories  duration
0       420        50
1       380        40
2       390        45
```

And I have a function to alter the value,

```
def alter_val(val):
    return val + 1
```

Now, as the documentation says, map() takes a function and iterator, it return another iterator. In my understanding, then it should work like this,

```
df["new_value"] = map(alter_val, df["calories"])
```

But it doesn't work. Shows

```
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

However, it works if I use the following code,

```
df["new"] = df["calories"].map(add_cal)
```

But it does not follow for documented approach map(function, series)

Can someone please take some time to explain the correct way, and why is it so?

Comment: did you try df["new_value"] = list(map(alter_val, df["calories"])) ? map() returns a map object (iterator)

Comment: These are two different "map" functions. The one you tried to use is a general-purpose Python function, the other is a pandas dataframe method.

Comment: @farbiondriven, Thanks for the comment. I got it. However, can you comment on, why df["calories"].map(add_cal) works?

Comment: @alexis Thanks a million! Now that makes clear sense!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns an iterator that *yields* results, not *returns* results, which means it's results are not actually calculated until you explicitly "ask" for them. Try this:

```py
list(map(alter_val, df["calories"]))
```

When you convert an iterator to a list, it has to calculate all of the results and store them in memory.

Despite that, I would stick to pandas `.map()` method, as it appears to be cleaner in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Convert the map output to list

```
df["new_value"] = list(map(alter_val, df["calories"]))
```